# Removing from array of dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I use UserDefualt to save array of Dictionary:

```
let pref = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
var fav=pref.arrayForKey("favRecipes")!;
        fav.append(self.dict);
        pref.setObject(fav, forKey: "favRecipes");
```

before i save another data i check if it already exist:

```
@IBAction func addToFavorites(sender: UIButton) {
    //not exist
    if !isFavorite(){
        var fav=pref.arrayForKey("favRecipes")!;
        fav.append(self.dict);
        pref.setObject(fav, forKey: "favRecipes");
        print("added");
    } //exist
    else{
        ;
    }
}
private func isFavorite()->Bool{
    var fav=pref.arrayForKey("favRecipes")!;
    for r in fav{
        if r["id"]! as! Int==id{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The purpose of this code is to add something to your favorites list, and if its already there u have the option to remove it.
for some reason i'm not succeeding to do the last part.

this my try so far:

```
 func remove(event:UIAlertAction!){
        var fav=pref.arrayForKey("favRecipes")!;

        for r in fav{
            if r["id"]! as! Int==id{
               pref.removeObjectForKey("\(id)");
                //pref.synchronize();
                //fav=pref.arrayForKey("favRecipes")!;
                //print(r["id"] as! Int);

            }
        }
    }
```

ofcourse i tried to look and search about removing from dictionarys at userDefualt but nothing helps.

Comment: @luk2302 using ; is not wrong and there isn't any rule that says we shouldn't use semicolons even tough it doesn't do anything in swift. It's upto the programmer to decide it. Instead of being rude, you can try and answer the question or use comment section to provide suggestion to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @iamyogish there are coding standards, you do not use `;` in swift, you write variable names in camel case, you write class names in pascal case, etc. Nothing you *have* to do, but something you certainly *should* do - always. from the beginning of programming you should be aware of the coding standards in the given language: don't use `;` - this is not objective-c

Comment: @luk2302 I agree one has to follow the coding standards. You could have told the guy to use it in a nicer way, the way you commented it out about the semicolons it was rude that's what I want to say. And yeah FYI , please check the apple documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID316  - which says Unlike many other languages, Swift does not require you to write a semicolon (;) after each statement in your code, although you can do so if you wish. It's upto the dev to use ;

Comment: and you can write almost your entire program in one line, just because you *can* does not mean you should.

Comment: @luk2302 dude what are you trying to impose ? Standards are standards and they're not rules okay?. And I agree with you that a good dev should follow coding standards. The point I am making is try to be polite in your answers or comments. Just don't be rude. Did you get it ?? Don't be RUDE please. Thanks.

Comment: I only did it for u to undersand the all pic and be able to give i better answer, no ment to argument (: i will love to hear how would u ask the same q with less code and still be able to pass the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the array `fav` and write that array back into the userDefaults. There is no object with the key `\(id)` in the defaults, only an array for key `favRecipes` which in turn contains an entry for the key `id`.

```
func remove(event:UIAlertAction!){
    var fav = pref.arrayForKey("favRecipes")!
    fav = fav.filter { $0["id"] != id }
    pref.setObject(fav, forKey: "favRecipes")
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i only needed to add a cast "id" to Int and it worked!

Comment: @HayAbados good to know. I did not really know where your `id` came from. Glad to help